# Expected ratio of successes of Bernoulli provided total number of trials is N

Tags: probability-distributions

My question seems similar but not exactly explained by negative binomial
If I stop experiment when either k successes is reached or after N experiment
What is the expected ratio success/required number of experiments
Seems like limited case of negative binomial, discarding the tail

Thank you

Comment: So I take it that if $Y$ is the number of successes divided by the number of trials, you want $E(Y)$, Certainly one can write an *expression* for $E(Y)$. A "closed form" may not be achievable.

Comment: that's what I need. I tried to figure out E(Y) but it started to get very complicated. It seems to be a common problem so I hoped there is some kind of standard distribution that I missed out.

Comment: The difficulty, as you noticed, is that we let $n$ be the number of trials until the $k$-th success, in calculating $E(Y)$ we get an $n$ in the denominator.

Comment: how about estimating expected number of successes and expected number of trials (not their ratio)? It's not the same thing but at least I'd like to get the idea. Is there a simple approach for this?